# How to support Dictionary and List in untyped IEnumerable

Tags: c#, dictionary, combobox, ienumerable, xamarin.forms

I have a "ComboBox" UserControl/Widget/View ([xamarin.forms](/questions/tagged/xamarin.forms) `Picker`) where the **ItemsSource** can be a List or Dictionary. The ComboBox has the follwing properties and sycs between them:

```
SelectedItem : object;
SelectedValue : object;
SelectedValuePath : string;
DisplayMemberPath : string;
```

The "ComboBox" (`Picker`) has some internal properties too:

```
SelectedIndex : int;
Items : IList<string>;
```

*ItemsSource* is currently untyped `IEnumerable` - this way you can populate it from XAML with an `Dictionary` or `List`.

Problem comes when I try to set **SelectedItem** from knowing **SelectedIndex**.
I don't know the type of the `Dictionary` (i.e. `Dictionary<int, string>`). With a list it works fine:

```
this.SelectedItem = ((IEnumerable<object>)this.ItemsSource).ToArray()[this.SelectedIndex];
```

In order of using **Enumerable.ElementAt({index})** I must cast the IEnumerable to typed Dictionary. It will not work on IDictionary/Dictionary and I don't seem to be able to cast to `Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic>` either.

Additionally I would need to sync back SelectedIndex from SelectedItem changing which presents a similar issue. With a List I can just do

```
this.SelectedIndex = this.ItemsSource.IndexOf(this.SelectedItem);
```

This doesn't throw exception for an Dictionary, but returns -1.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you an idea, but this is by no means full proof and I have not tried it out in the context of your case.

Lets say I have

```
Dictionary<int,string> test = new Dictionary<int,string>();
```

with KVP values added

```
test.Add(1,"1");
test.Add(2,"2");
test.Add(3,"3");
```

Then you can use reflection to generate an IList which you can then use IndexOf or use an Indexer. 
As shown below

```
if (test is IDictionary)
{
    var list = GetListFromDictionary(test);
    if (list != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(list[1]);
        Console.WriteLine(list.IndexOf(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2,"2")));
    }
}
```

With the GetListFromDictionary being

```
public IList GetListFromDictionary(IDictionary dict)
{

        var type = dict.GetType();
        var newType = typeof(KeyValuePair<,>);
        var typeArgs = type.GetGenericArguments();
        var contructed  = newType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);        
        var toListMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().First(meth => meth.Name == "ToList");
        var method = toListMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { contructed });
        return method.Invoke(null, new object[] { dict}) as IList;

}
```

// PCL Version

```
    public IList GetListFromDictionary(IDictionary dict)
    {

        var type = dict.GetType();
        var newType = typeof(KeyValuePair<,>);
        var typeArgs = type.GenericTypeArguments;
        var contructed = newType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
        var toListMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetRuntimeMethods().First(meth => meth.Name == "ToList");
        var method = toListMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { contructed });
        return method.Invoke(null, new object[] { dict }) as IList;

    }
```

Comment: Yeah, that worked like a charm. Forgot to mention I roll PCL though, and I'm not sure there are equivalents for these reflection methods. Will investigate.